# Get schema of query's result without executing the query in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'd like to know the best way to retrieve the schema for a query's result WITHOUT executing the query. By Schema I want to know the name of the fields that will be returned and if they are boolean, literal or float, ...

For those familiar with SQL Server I want the same kind of behavior than using a FMTONLY.

At the moment my best approach is to perform a LIMIT 0 ... but anyway I'm nowhere to know the type of the returned fields.

Comment: To infer the types you can also do limit 1 and inspect that single row for types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeking is not generally possible.

Unlike SQL, neo4j is "schemaless", and the "schema" of a query result is generally dependent on the data in the DB. This means that, generally, a query's result schema cannot be known without actually executing the query.

Comment: I understand your point but if I write a return where I precisely define the expected properties like ```RETURN a.name, b.year``` ...  Can I receive something else than a field name (literal) and another field year (int) ?

Comment: There is currently no Cypher support for getting data types.